# NSURLSession: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

Im trying to get data back from my own API. I can see the data within my console log but it keeps giving me found nil error.

Heres my code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "linkHere")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "sol=\(name)&sector=\(sector)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        do {
            self.json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
        } catch let error as NSError{
         print("TEST Error \(error)")
        }

           if let parseJSON = self.json {


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailView") as! detailViewController
                     let x = parseJSON["sector"] as! String
                    vc.secLab = x
                    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
         }

    }
    task.resume()
```

Within my console log I can see the data see image below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you be more specific?

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Which line did it crash on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it's a bad idea to continue executing "good" code after catching an error and only printing it.

If you unwrap the casted type in the `try` branch, it becomes a non optional type on success otherwise the appropriate error is caught.

The syntax is supposed to look like

```
do {
  self.json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as! [AnyObject]
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailView") as! detailViewController
      let dict = self.json[0] as! [String:AnyObject]
      let x = dict["sector"] as! String
      vc.secLab = x
      self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
} catch let error as NSError{
  print("TEST Error \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Learned something new! After applying your changes and upon running i get the following error `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x4d927c) to 'NSDictionary' (0x4d9394).` At the `self.json = try` line.   Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: Allesandro mentioned correctly that the json object is an array rather than a dictionary. You have to cast to `NSArray` or a Swift type and retrieve the values accordingly. I updated my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake should've cast it properly thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have cast the json to an optional NSDictionary, but your json response is a an array look square bracket in the screenshot you have attached it.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake should've cast it properly thank you!